# PHP - How to limit a foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have maybe some stupid question.

Here is my code:

```
            $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);

            $LimitLoop = 50;            

            foreach($customers as $customer)
            {
                $email=$customer->getEmail();
                $CustomerPhone = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
                $CustomerName = $customer->getName();
                $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();

                if($EnableSMSNotification==1 && $smstext!="") {

                $api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
                        "username" => $TextMagicUsername, 
                        "password" => $TextMagicPassword
                    ));

                    // Use this number for testing purposes. This is absolutely free.

                $phones = array($CustomerPhone);

                    $results = $api->send($smstext, $phones, true);
                    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                    $sql_insert = "insert into VivasIndustries_SmsHistory values ('','$CustomerName','$CustomerPhone','$CustomerEmail','$smstext',NOW())";
                    $write->query($sql_insert);



                }   




            }
```

This is a simple `foreach loop`.
How can i limit it to the value pointed in `$LimitLoop` ?

How can i fetch only a limited number of results in this loop ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to break more than once, you may refer this:[break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a `for` loop is out of the question then you would need to manually add an incrementing counter to perform the same logic.  Something like this:

```
$LimitLoop = 50;
$i = 0;
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    if ($i++ >= $LimitLoop) {
        break;
    }
    // the rest of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can save the variable $i from the other examples if you use something like this

```
$LimitLoop = 50;

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
  /* your code to run */
  /* ..... */


  /* at the bottom */
  $LimitLoop--;
  if ($LimitLoop===0) {
    break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);

$LimitLoop = 50;  

$counter = 0; //Add a means of counting how many times it's been through the loop

foreach($customers as $customer)
{

    $email=$customer->getEmail();
    $CustomerPhone = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    $CustomerName = $customer->getName();
    $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();

    if($EnableSMSNotification==1 && $smstext!="") {

    $api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
            "username" => $TextMagicUsername, 
            "password" => $TextMagicPassword
        ));

        // Use this number for testing purposes. This is absolutely free.

    $phones = array($CustomerPhone);

        $results = $api->send($smstext, $phones, true);
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $sql_insert = "insert into VivasIndustries_SmsHistory values ('','$CustomerName','$CustomerPhone','$CustomerEmail','$smstext',NOW())";
        $write->query($sql_insert);



    }   

    $counter++; //Increment the counter
    if($counter >= $LimitLoop) break; //Break the loop if we have enough results

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd either want to use a `break` statement or use a `for` loop that runs up to `$LimitLoop`.

For loop (I use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function as `$customers` could be an associate array or have missing numeric keys, etc. Indexing the array of keys (which will have numeric ordering) then assures we always get the next key):

```
$keys = array_keys($customers);
for ($i = 0; $i < $LimitLoop; $i++) {
    $customer = $customers[$keys[$i]];
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Note: You would have to also insert some more logic to check that you do have 50 customers with the above loop as else it'll start throwing warnings about accessing invalid offsets in the array.

break:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    // your code
    $i++;
    if ($i >= $LimitLoop) {
        break;
    }
}
```